# Email form disabled when the plugin fires

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I've register my plugin step with the following information

```
Eventing Pipeline state of execution:- Post operation
Execution mode:- Synchronous
Deployment:- Server
```

My Plugin is collecting description of email entity, making the doc file of that description and then downloading the file.

Now the problem is that when the plugin triggers it work fine as it have too but the email form is get disabled.

I want to seek your kind suggestion and helps in this manner.

Comment: What message is you plugin firing on?

Answer (score 0):

```
If you do not want your form to halt/disable

Change the plugin mode from:

Execution Mode: Synchronous to Asynchronous
```

It will call the registered plugin in a queue and the form will not be disabled.